# What is a "stone core"?

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical, non-native-english

In a book I'm reading, I found this:

> Of course, even the most primitive tools of *Home erectus* (flaked **stone cores** called 'hand-axes') are far more sophisticaed than anything used by chimpanzees, […]

Why *flaked stone cores* instead of *flaked stones*? What role is *cores* playing here?

I think the topic is possibly highly technical, but I think my question is still on-topic.

---

Probably the answer is [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_core), but I honestly still don't understand what information *flaked stone cores* is supposed to convey in addition to what *flaked stones* would convey, in this specific context.

In other words, how would a *flaked stone* be different from a *flaked stone core*, assuming the former is a thing or can at least be a plausible locution to a native speaker?

Or maybe the truth is simply that *flaked stone cores* is just the name these things were given, and that *flaked stones* could have equally been chosen alternatively?

Comment: Technical term in archeology ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_core ... a "flaked stone core" is a type of tool made by *Homo erectus*.  The maker removes flakes from a stone in such a way that the core remaining afterward has a sharp edge, and can be used as an axe.

Comment: @GEdgar Please write answers, not comments.

Comment: Technical questions about prehistory are on-topic on [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Encouraging non-specialists to give technical answers is likely to result in incorrect information being conveyed.

Comment: The full OED has definition #5: *The remaining central portion of a mass from which the superficial parts have been cut or chipped away; e.g. of a hay-rick, and **in Prehistoric Archaeology of a flint nodule,** whence flakes have been chipped for flint knives, etc. Also attributive, applied to implements consisting of a **trimmed core of flint** or to cultures characterized by this type of implement.*

Comment: @StuartF: that's right in a way, but questions on History SE tend to get refused unless the question includes evidence that the questioner has researched the matter.

Comment: @Colin Fine Isn't that the correct procedure here too?

Comment: It is apparently a property of the mineral _flint_ that it occurs naturally in nodules - separate or separable chunks of the rock. When knapping a nodule, flakes are chipped off one edge, making it sharp but leaving the "core" of the nodule as a handle. Basically, it's a hand-held rock with one very sharp edge.

Comment: @ColinFine, what type of research? I've linked in my question the same wikipedia page that is linked off the first comment. I know what the word _core_ means and I have read through that wiki page. The point is that I'm not a native speaker and I just can't understand everything from a page targeting native people. I'll add a few more info to my question.

Comment: I don't suppose any dictionary is going to explicitly explain *why* we use "core" in this way. But my guess is it's at least *partly* by way of extension from things like ***apple*** cores - so it's ***the hard bit in the middle*** of some very roughly spherical "lump" (such as an apple, flint nodule, or kidney).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe. But still, what reasearch have I missed to do for getting the question closed?

Comment: I think *however* you revise your question text, it's always going to be "unwanted" on ELU, which is for [*linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It seems to me you've got your answer here anyway - but if you don't like having such questions closed, just post them on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (where they *are* "wanted" and "On Topic").

Comment: This is not an answer, just my interpretation from a language point of view after reading... First, you have to get a "core" by [lithic reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_core) (which involves flaking). After that, you can further flake that core to fashion a tool. So a core = a flaked rock, and a flaked core = a knife.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: in theory that is the procedure here too, but it seems to be applied much more rigorously (and with a higher standard) in History SE.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141888/discussion-on-question-by-enlico-what-is-a-stone-core).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the English language (but terminology independent of the language), and it lacks proper research.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia defines a [lithic core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_core) as the nucleus resulting from the detachment of one or more flakes from a stone.

> In archaeology, a lithic core is a distinctive artifact that results
> from the practice of lithic reduction. In this sense, a core is the
> scarred nucleus resulting from the detachment of one or more flakes
> from a lump of source material or tool stone, usually by using a hard
> hammer precursor such as a hammerstone. The core is marked with the
> positive scars of these flakes. The surface area of the core which
> received the blows necessary for detaching the flakes is referred to
> as the striking platform. The core may be discarded or shaped further
> into a core tool, such as can be seen in some types of handaxe. In
> archaeology, a lithic core is a distinctive artifact that results from
> the practice of lithic reduction. In this sense, a core is the scarred
> nucleus resulting from the detachment of one or more flakes from a
> lump of source material or tool stone, usually by using a hard hammer
> precursor such as a hammerstone. The core is marked with the positive
> scars of these flakes. The surface area of the core which received the
> blows necessary for detaching the flakes is referred to as the
> striking platform. The core may be discarded or shaped further into a
> core tool, such as can be seen in some types of handaxe.

However, it seems that **core** has different meanings according to Archeologists.

Shennon Mac Pherson wrote that there is a [difference between core and tools](https://www.academia.edu/1444101/Tool_v_Core_New_Approaches_in_the_Analysis_of_Stone_Tool_Assemblages).

> The implications for Neandertal behavior and for how archaeologists
> study it are significantly altered if these artifacts arecores
> designed to produce very small flakes, flakes so small that
> mostarchaeologists do not even study them. In other words, it matters
> whether theywere tools or cores. ... The purpose of a **core** was to
> produce flakes some of which were then made into tools.

On the other hand, [core tools](https://www.britannica.com/technology/hand-tool/Stone-as-a-material#ref424390) are defined by Encyclopædia Britannica as the most primitive category of flaked stones

> Three principal types of tools appeared in the long Paleolithic
> Period, with substantial variations occurring within each type. The
> types are distinguished principally by workmanship but also vary in
> size and appearance and are known as core, flake, and blade tools. The
> core tools are the largest; the earliest and most primitive were made
> by working on a fist-sized piece of rock (**core**) with a similar rock
> (hammerstone) and knocking off several large flakes on one side to
> produce a jagged but sharp crest. This was a general-purpose implement
> for the roughest work, such as hacking, pounding, or cutting. The
> angle of the cutting edge was rather large because of the sphericity
> of the stone. In time, thinner, sharper, and more versatile core tools
> were developed.

According to the context, i.e. "the *most primitive* tools of Home erectus (flaked stone cores called '*hand-axes*')", we may assume that, in this sentence, **core is used to define the flaked stones of lower paleolithic**,  rather than (1) a tool used to shave the stone or (2) flaked stone from other paleolithic periods.

Answer (score 0):

They are called stone cores and not just stones because that is what they are.

You find a stone, then you hammer away the edges, and you are left with a stone core, usually lighter, easier to grip, and with useful sharp edges.